# How should we can generate the allure report at build level

Tags: jenkins, allure

I successfully integrate the allure into jenkins.But when i run job i get only latest build job.How should we get allure report for every build

Comment: Do you run all the maven commands? `mvn clean`, `mvn test`, `mvn site`? Locally I run `mvn jetty:run` afterwards, not sure how you should do it in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Allure does not provide any historical info per build, currently. At the Allure v2 would be feature to check current test results vs previous and calculate success rate. Also Allure Server will be introduced during this year.